# What are these headers and values: HTTP_X_FB_HTTP_ENGINE = Liger, HTTP_X_PURPOSE = preview and HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH = com.facebook.katana?

Tags: web-development, http, http-headers

I'm trying to debug an issue in my website, and i see these headers in my page view log:

[HTTP_X_FB_HTTP_ENGINE] => Liger
[HTTP_X_PURPOSE] => preview
[HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => com.facebook.katana

They are sent by visits using Facebook's in-app browser. HTTP_X_FB_HTTP_ENGINE=Liger sometimes comes together with HTTP_X_PURPOSE=preview.

What are these headers and these specific values? How they affect a request?

Comment: Bots often fake headers. If you can't find information about them using a Google search, that's likely the case. Please refer to the comments in your initial question.

Comment: See http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/magento-website-hammering-facebook-liger/ and https://www.facebook.com/business/help/www/1514372351922333 . There are other useful pages out there, but this will get you (rather, people who visit this question) started.